# How to disable keyboard inputs when using Entry on Tkinter on python?

Tags: python, tkinter, screen, disabled-input

How can I disable keyboard input entries when using Entry on Tkinter in python
I was coding for a calculator project in python. So I need to make a screen like text box using Entry.
I couldn't remove keyboard inputs from the Entry field.

Comment: Have you tried to put the entry in disabled state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable keyboard input into an Entry widget, disable resizing of tkinter window and hide the console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175572/how-do-i-disable-keyboard-input-into-an-entry-widget-disable-resizing-of-tkinte)

Comment: You can use `Label` with border so that it looks like a readonly `Entry`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the state of Entry widget to DISABLED.

Example:-

```
win = tk.Tk()
ent = Entry(win, state=DISABLED)
ent.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can disable keyboard characters from an Entry field in Tkinter using:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

txtDisplay = Entry(root, width=28, justify=RIGHT)    
txtDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, pady=1)
txtDisplay.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")          # Disable characters from keyboard

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This won't prevent you from pasteing data with the mouse.